# decimal digit validation with negative sign

Tags: php

I need to support decimal digit validation with a negative sign using php.

I have already used `preg_match('/^\d+\.\d+$/', latitude)`.

It's working fine but when latitude comes as `-92.67` it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this expression instead:

```
^-?\d+\.\d+$
```

So your code would look like:

```
preg_match('/^-?\d+\.\d+$/', latitude)
```

The `-?` simply says that the `-` is optional

Answer (score 0):

`\d` matches only numbers so you just have to allow an optionnal `-` like this :

`preg_match('/^-?\d+.\d+$/', latitude)`

`?` means that the preceding char must be present 0 or 1 time (see the doc : http://php.net/manual/regexp.reference.repetition.php )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `floatval()` and `is_numeric()`?

"floatval — Get float value of a variable"

http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

"is_numeric — Finds whether a variable is a number or a numeric string"

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Comment: You can run `var_dump(floatval('2 or 3 places'), floatval('pink'));` to figure out why this isn't a good approach for validation.

Comment: What if we also use the is_numeric() function? Does that make my answer helpful or should I just delete it?

Comment: It really depends on the exact specs. If `+0123.45e6` is acceptable then `is_numeric()` is possibly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Besides adding an optional hyphen `-?` you  have to escape the dot `\.` or else it would match for example `-9z90` or `-9 90` because the dot matches any character.

Your regex could look like:

[`^-?\d+\.\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/UpvYdT/1)